# Eloquent Javascript Exercise 5.2. Help organizing thoughts

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Question Prompt:
Using the example data set from this chapter, compute the average age difference between mothers and children (the age of the mother when the child is born). You can use the average function defined earlier in this chapter.

Note that not all the mothers mentioned in the data are themselves present in the array. The byName object, which makes it easy to find a person’s object from their name, might be useful here.

### JS File: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/ancestry.js

My approach

1. Create an object with "mothers" as the keys, with arrays containing "mother's DOB, daughter's name, daughter's DOB".
2. Calculate mother's age when having baby with "daughter's DOB" - "mother's DOB"
3. Pass values into average function provided, written as

   function average(array) {
   function plus(a, b) {
    return a + b; 
   } 
   return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
   }

---

I'm stuck at step 1

Step 1 - split into sub-steps

a. remove all data points where mother = null && where mother's DOB is unknown (her name is listed as "mother", but there is no separate entry for her)

```
Filter out all "null" entries:
    var hasMom = ancestry.filter(function(person) {
    return person.mother != null;});
```

Map an array of only mother names:

```
  var momSet = hasMom.map(function(person) {return person.mother;});
```

Create function that will test if an entry is contained within a set

```
function isInSet(set, person) {return set.indexOf(person.name) > -1};
```

Apply function in filter

```
var hasKnownMother = hasMom.filter(function(person) 
        {return isInSet(momSet, person)});
```

b. create a byName object of these mothers with their daughter and DOB

```
 var byName = {};
 hasKnownMother.forEach(function(person) {
       byName[person.name] = [person.born, person.mother];});
```

QUESTION: at this point, I've filtered out 34 entries to only 10. Cross-checking names and entries, I am not getting the results I intended.

What am I doing incorrectly? What should I rethink?

c. search .JS file for mother's name, add(push?) her DOB into the byName object

QUESTION: I have no idea what to do if I want to search the byName object's keys (mother names), match them to the ancestry .JS database keys, and add .JS's DOB entry to my byName object.

I'm thinking a For In loop, or a bind?

Comment: ewwww. using strings as keys.. What were they thinking? I am sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient way would be to build a hash of people using name as a key so you're not constantly iterating. After that, you can iterate the original array again, this time checking that the mother exists in the data and pushing the difference to an output array as you go.

```
var ancestryJSON = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE),
byName = {},
ageDifferences = [];

function initNameHash(){
    for(var i = 0, len = ancestryJSON.length; i < len; i++){
        byName[ancestryJSON[i].name] = ancestryJSON[i];
    }
}

function setAgeDifferences(){

    for(var i = 0, len = ancestryJSON.length; i < len; i++){

        var child = ancestryJSON[i];

        if(child.mother !== null &&
           byName[child.mother] !== undefined){

            var mother = byName[child.mother];
            var ageDifference = child.born - mother.born;

            ageDifferences.push(ageDifference);
        }

    }

}

function average(array) { 
    function plus(a, b) { return a + b; } 
    return array.reduce(plus) / array.length; 
}

initNameHash();
setAgeDifferences();

console.log(ageDifferences);
alert(average(ageDifferences));
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oafd8hgL/

Comment: Does this answer your question or were you looking for something else?

Comment: Are you saying it's a requirement for some sort of assignment to use those specific methods? If not, my answer accomplishes the goal with less and more efficient code.

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me. I'm looking to use map/filter/forEach to apply my knowledge of higher order functions. Could you explain the solution listed at http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.2? I am having trouble understanding the logic in the **differences* variable declared

Comment: No argument there. Looking at the byName[child.mother] code a bit more makes sense now in my head. thank you.

Comment: Sure. So .filter returns an array containing person objects where byName[person.mother] != null; is true. In javascript != null is equivalent to !== undefined || !== null. So if the mother's name isn't a key in the byName hash, those objects are filtered out of the output array. Then .map essentially iterates each person object of that output array, creating a new array where each element is the result of the return statement. That final output array is then assigned to the differences variable. Make sense?

Comment: yes! thank you. I've been stuck on this challenge for a couple weeks on my own. definitely should have come here sooner haha